# Can we lock the Bundle which is already in workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, bundles

I have two question regarding the bundle workflow

If I start the workflow on a Bundle , can I add more items to this Bundle.

Can I Lock a bundle which is already in Workflow .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add items to bundle if it's allowed by your current activity definition. In Visio Workflow designer, when creating a process definition you can define behavior for each of the activities. Bundle which is in workflow is already locked, unless other is specified in activity definition.